# How to delete all but certain values from many JSON files?

Tags: command-line, automator, json

I've used `youtube-dl` to download all my videos from Youtube. With these, are created a JSON file for each video file. inside these JSON files is a LOT of junk. but there are 3 items/values/categories(?) that i want to keep, the rest can be deleted.

Those things are

```
{"upload_date": "value",
"fulltitle": "value",
"description": "value"}
```

So I either need to:

- delete all but these 3 items & save the file, or
- extract these 3 items to a new file & delete the old one.

How can I do this with Automator or with shell tools in Terminal?

Comment: You might take a look at [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) or [`miller`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller). There's also the [JSON lib for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) - if you're into that. I used it a few years ago for a weather app - there's a [YouTube channel that got me started.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N6a-VLBa2I)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one of the ways I would do it...

The following was tested and worked for me under **macOS Catalina** 10.15.6.

I downloaded `jq` from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ under the **OS X** section:

> - jq 1.6 binary for [64-bit](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-osx-amd64)

In **Terminal**, I ran the following *commands*:

```
cd ~/Downloads
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine jq-osx-amd64
sudo cp jq-osx-amd64 /usr/local/bin/jq
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/jq
```

<sup>• **Note:** If `/usr/local/bin` does not already exist, it must first be created with e.g.: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`</sup>

The aforementioned steps have now set up `jq` for use from the *command line* in **Terminal**, or from a **Run Shell Script** *action* in **Automator**, or a `do shell script` *command* using **AppleScript**.

Downloading a video from **YouTube** with `youtube-dl` using the `--write-info-json` *option*, I then used the *example* **shell script** *code*, shown below, in a **Run Shell Script** *action* in an **Automator** *workflow* as a *Service/Quick Action* to process the **JSON** *file* so it would only have the *keys* you've mentioned.

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
for f in "$@"; do
    [[ -f $f ]] || continue
    [[ $f =~ .*\.json$ ]] || continue
    fn="${f##*/}"
    tmpfile="$(mktemp /tmp/"${fn}.XXXXXX")" || exit 1
    /usr/local/bin/jq '{"upload_date": .upload_date, "fulltitle": .fulltitle, "description": .description}' "$f" > "$tmpfile"
    mv "$tmpfile" "$f"
done
```

With this setup as shown in the image further below, I select the **JSON** *file*, created by `youtube-dl` using the `--write-info-json` *option*, in **Finder** and then *right-click* on it selecting **Cleanup youtube-dl JSON** from the *context menu*.

It then produced a **JSON** *file* with the following *example structure*, while overwriting the original **JSON** *file*:

```json
{
  "upload_date": "20080913",
  "fulltitle": "Jerry Seinfeld returns to Comedy on the Letterman show",
  "description": "Jerry Seinfeld returns to Comedy on the Letterman show"
}
```

[image: Automator Service/Quick Action workflow]

---

**Notes:**

- The example **JSON** *file* was created from the output of:

  ```
  youtube-dl --write-info-json https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JOsxxm-RnQ
  ```
- The *example* **shell script** *code*, as coded, can handle multiple selected **JSON** *files* in **Finder** at the same time.
- While the *example* **shell script** *code* does contain some *error handling*, nonetheless it does not backup the original **JSON** *file(s)* before overwriting. Additional *code* is required to be added if that is something you need/want.
- The *example* **shell script** *code*, as coded, does not contain any *error handling* in regards to the `jq` *command* used and is only meant to be used on **JSON** *files* created by `youtube-dl` using the `--write-info-json` *option* with the assumption that the target *keys* always exist under the circumstances. Otherwise, additional *error handling* may be required.
- The format of the  **JSON** *files* created by `youtube-dl` using the `--write-info-json` *option* are *flat formatted*, meaning it is written all on one line. The output of the `jq` *command*, as written, produces *multi-line* output. If you desire *flat formatted* output, you can use the `-c` *option*, e.g.,: `jq -c ...`
- The *example* **shell script** *code* can be used in a standard  **shell script**, made executable, and run from the *command line* in **Terminal**.
- The *error handling* can be removed from the *example* **shell script** *code* and formatted so it can also be use as a one-liner after changing directory the where the **JSON** *files* are located. e.g.:

  ```
  for f in *.json; do jq '{"upload_date": .upload_date, "fulltitle": .fulltitle, "description": .description }' "$f" > "tmp"; mv tmp "$f"; done
  ```

<sup>• **Note:** This overwrites the original *file* without a backup.</sup>

- **NOTE:** **JSON** *files* are not just ordinary plain text files per se, they are specially formatted, and one should not *parse* them with *utilities* such as `sed`, `awk`, etc., and instead use a *utility* expressly designed to work with **JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)** *files*! `jq` is a *utility* designed to work with **JSON** *files*.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!! that was PERFECTLY Explained & EXACTLY what i needed. SO much appreciation!!!!! i'm floored at your generosity & detailed solution.